# How to send messages from a node running python to arduino?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upload the following code to Arduino.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
ros::NodeHandle nh;

void messageCb(const std_msgs::Float64& msg)
{
  if(msg.data > 1.0)
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // blink the led
    else 
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // Turn off led
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float64> sub("your_topic", &messageCb);
 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}
void loop()
{
  
 nh.spinOnce();
 delay(1);
}
```

I use this code to turn on a LED connected to PIN13. The code receives a signal from the topic "your_topic", then if the signal is bigger than 1.0 it turns the LED.

From the terminal, I use the next code to publish to "your_topic": rostopic pub your_topic std_msgs/Float64 2

Though this code works, I now want to publish using python. I tried the succeeding code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from project_1.msg import *
from random import randint

rospy.init_node('Arduino_hear_my_whispers')
pub = rospy.Publisher('your_topic', Arduino_message, queue_size=10)
rnd = randint(0,2)
print "the number is " + str(rnd)
message=Arduino_message(x=rnd)
pub.publish(message)
rate = rospy.Rate(10)
rate.sleep()
```

Although the code worked, the LED did not turn on. Can someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279880/how-to-send-messages-from-a-node-running-python-to-arduino?/) by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a couple of things going on here:

1. What are the contents of `Arduino_message`? This looks like it's a custom message but we don't know what it looks like
2. The `your_topic` topic from the Arduino's perspective is expecting a `Float64` message but your Python node is publishing an `Arduino_message` message (containing an `int` for the `x` parameter)
3. You're not looping so you're only publishing once which means you'll have to keep re-running the node until you get `2` (which may be what you want, but IMO is tedious to test)

This should help:

1. Post the contents of your custom `Arduino_message` so we can see what's going on there
2. Match the data (message) type of the `your_topic` topic. Either go with your custom `Arduino_message`, a `Float64`, or an `int`
3. At least test this out using a loop until you get it working.

Also, I notice that you have a print statement in there. Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the result of it? Otherwise this answer is just a guess.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) on 2018-01-15**:
Here is the content of the Arduino_message.msg file:
float64 x
I also run the script in a loop and found the following error: [WARN] [1516049736.697616][std_msgs/Float64] vs. [project_1/Arduino_message] ...
It is like the format std_msgs/Float64 and float64 are different.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-15**:
@JollyRogers: please update your question with the full error and the definition

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem importing FLoat 64 from std_msg.msg. I still do not know why ROS is not recognizing the float64 type from the Arduino_message file. The final code is presented below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import  Float64
from random import randint
from time import sleep

rospy.init_node('Arduino_hear_my_whispers')
pub = rospy.Publisher('your_topic', Float64, queue_size=10)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rnd = randint(0,2)
        print "the number is " + str(rnd)
        message=Float64(rnd)
        pub.publish(message)
        rate = rospy.Rate(100)
        sleep(3)
rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) with karma: 58 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-15**:
So, basically what I suggested? I think that you should go through the [ROS tutorials for `rospy`](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Tutorials) again. You should use the `Rate` object's `sleep()` method instead of Python's. Also, you should review how to use custom messages.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-15**:
If you still can't figure out how to use your custom message then feel free to ask a new question.